# How to remove a line containing non-ascii values in python

Tags: python

I am reading a huge tab-delimited file one line at a time and keep that line if value of a particular field is more than k. Since this field is stored as string, I typecast that value as `int(x)`. I am getting the following error in a particular line.  When I try to print that line, I see entries similar to this.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:


'\xc3\xd2u\xc4\x99\xc3\xc2\xe8v\x00\xcb\xa5T\x13\xc5F\xe7\x00\xc9*\x8e\xc5vV\xc0W\xe3\xc1\xee\xe2\xc0\xa3i\x00\xcc\r\x11\xc8\xaf\xb2\xc0\xa9+\xc2\x9b\x13\x00\xcb<\xbe\xc1C\x07\xc6\xd6%\xc0}\xd7\x00\xcc\xdc?\xc3%t\xc0o\x1a\x13\xc5#\x9e\x00\xcb.\xf6\xc5\xe5G\x00\xcb2\x00\x13\xc0N\xa5\xc2cr\x96\xec\x98-\xc6\x025\x00\xcd\x04\xff\xc0\xc6}\xc1+\xdf\xc1j\x14\xc0\xff+......'
```

What is an efficient way to detect such line or remove such line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example,

```
if any(ord(x) > 127 for x in line)....
```

or

```
import re
if re.search(r'[\x80-\xFF]', line)...
```

In response to the edit, I'd suggest something like

```
for line in file:
   fields = line.split('\t')
   if len(fields) != <expected number of fields>:
        # invalid line
        continue
   try:
       k = int(fields[<field number>]
   except ValueError:
       # invalid line
       continue
    if k < <threshold>:
       # skip it
       continue
    # now process the line
```